# Nested for loop through different sets of data in R

Tags: r

How can I create a nested for loop that uses different data sets (each consisting of several data files) as input and then save the results variable- specific?

I have written a for loop that subsets different climate data files for one country and then sums up the values for Temperature.

The data looks like this and is given for every day in every region of both countries (one file=one region)

```
Date      |Prec |Temperature
----------|-----|-----------                                          
13-01-1992| 1   |   1
14-01-1992| 0   |   1.5
15-01-1993| 0.8 |   -0.4
16-01-1993| 0   |   -2.2
17-01-1994| 0   |   -2.35
13-01-1994| 0.3 |   -2.95
14-01-1995| 1   |   -8.95
15-01-1995| 2   |   -7.25
16-01-1996| 1.5 |   -6
17-01-1996| 0   |   -8.3
13-02-1997| 1   |   -0.3
14-02-1997| 0.1 |   -0.15
15-02-1998| 0   |   -2.5
16-02-1998| 0.2 |   -3.4
17-02-1999| 0.9 |   -0.4
16-03-1999| 2.6 |   8.4
17-03-2000| 1.7 |   11
18-03-2000| 4.7 |   4.65
19-03-2001| 1   |   2.95
20-03-2001| 0.6 |   4.7
13-08-2002| 2   |   22.35
14-08-2002| 1   |   20
15-08-2003| 1.7 |   21.4
16-08-2003| 0.5 |   21.55
17-08-2004| 0.4 |   21.5
17-02-2004| 0.3 |   -0.6
18-02-2005| 0.8 |   -3.4
19-02-2005| 1.2 |   -3
20-02-2006| 0.8 |   2
21-02-2006| 6   |   1.2
```

Now I want this to run over data sets of two different countries.
A different number of data-files belongs to each country.
I tried this:

```
Temperature<-matrix(1995:2006,12,1)
Country_A<-c("1.csv","2.csv","3.csv")
Country_B<-c("4.csv","5.csv")
country<-c(Country_A, Country_B)
country_names<-c("Country_A "," Country_B ")

for(j in 1:2)
{for(i in country[j]) {
name <- country_names[j]  
Data<-read.csv(i, header=TRUE, sep = ",")
Data$Dates<-as.Date(Data$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")
Data95<-subset(Data, Dates>="1995-01-01")
Data$Years<- as.numeric(format(Data$Dates, "%Y"))
Temperature<-cbind(Temperature, aggregate(Data95$Column1, by= list(Data95$Years),FUN=sum))}}
```

Instead of looping through one country after each other, like this only the files 1 and 2 are addressed. I think the problem is about 
`country<-c(Country_A, Country_B)`

I assume that an array could be the solution to address the countries separately and maybe also to save the Temperature results country specific.
Unfortunately I am quite new to R and therefore I don’t know how to set this up.
I would be very happy about any help!

Comment: Share a samle data set that one of the csv files is having. For loop shall be quite slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Temperature<-matrix(1995:2006,12,1)

# Below are just for understanding. Country_A represents just the names of files in the A directory    
# Country_A<-c("1.csv","2.csv","3.csv")
# Country_B<-c("4.csv","5.csv")

lA=list.files(path = "countryA_pathname", pattern= ".csv")
lB=list.files(path = "countryB_pathname", pattern= ".csv")

l1A = paste0("countryA_pathname", lA)
# l1A = c("countryA_pathname/1.csv", "countryA_pathname/2.csv", "countryA_pathname/3.csv")
l1B = paste0("countryB_pathname", lB)
# l1B = c("countryB_pathname/4.csv", "countryB_pathname/5.csv")

abc <- function(path)
{
  Data = read.csv(path)
  Data$Date<-as.Date(Data$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")
  Data$Years<- as.numeric(format(Data$Date, "%Y"))
  Data95 = subset(Data , Date >="1995-01-01")
  Temperature <- ddply(Data95, "Years", function(x) sum(x$Temperature))[-1]#JUST EXTRACTS THE SUM COLUMN
  Temperature
}

LA = lapply(l1A, abc)
LB = lapply(l1B, abc)

dA = cbind(Temperature, as.data.frame(LA))
colnames(dA) <- c("Temperature", lA)
dB = cbind(Temperature, as.data.frame(LB))
colnames(dB) <- c("Temperature", lB)
```

Hope this works

Comment: add the data to the question itself..secondly does my answer work for you?!

Comment: Partly it did. I assumed it should have been L=lapply (l3,abc) instead of l since this was not defined?! However, like this, still the temperature sums are calculated for every single file. I do not know if there is a possibility to make an average over all files for each l1 and l2 for each year..

Comment: okay...so to get this right...if there are 5 dataframes each in pathnameA and B, then you want the average of all 10df? and yeah, yes it is l3

Comment: I would like to have an average value for each year, one time for all 5 files in pathname A and one time for all 5 files in B .... Thank you already!

Comment: once you subset Data95, how do you want to group the data? In "by = Data95$Years" which is this column Years?

Comment: I am sorry, I left this line out when I aimed at simplifying the code, I did this Data$Years<- as.numeric(format(Data$Dates, "%Y")) (which is know included in the code above as well)

Comment: okay thanks, I can share the solution provided you give me a better view of data. more observations with values across years such that I can work on it directly

Comment: I tried to include a larger data set with 2 observations each year above - I hope it is accessible like that.

Comment: Hey I have updated the answer. Let me know of any queries

Comment: Yes it worked - thank you! After taking the mean over each row in dA (excluding the year) I got the result I needed.

Comment: glad I could help!